# What is the data structure used by Recycle bin & hows it implemented

Tags: windows, filesystems, recycle-bin, algorithm

In a Windows file system, we cannot created a folder or file with the same name. For example, New Folder. If there is a existing folder already named as "New Folder" and if we create another folder with the same name, it prompts or creates "New Folder 2". I recently deleted various folders named New Folder.

Recycle bin does not complaint if both folders have same names. I wanted to know how "Recycle bin" is functioning. It is a file system as well. How is it implemented, what is the data structure used. I want to implement a similar file system at work.

I can think that even though it shows the users that files are deleted but the reference is to the same place from where it got deleted and allowing same file names.

Comment: That's just the name your shown, the actual name behind the scenes is different. Your question is also very broad, are you suggesting you didn't find any information at all on the internet/books?

Comment: Related/possible duplicate questions: [How does the Recycle Bin work?](http://superuser.com/questions/368890/), [How can the recycle bin hold multiple files with the same name?](http://superuser.com/questions/590039/), [How can we insert multiple objects with the same name into the Windows Recycle Bin?](http://superuser.com/questions/614127/)